# How to open colorbox group from non-colorbox element click?

Tags: jquery, href, colorbox, rel

I want to open the [jquery colorbox plugin](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) from an element not related to the colorbox group of photos. There is no colorbox `.open()` method, only an `open:true` property used in setting it that just tells it to immediately open.

I've tried:

```
$('#myElement').click(function () {
    $.colorbox({
        open: true
    });
});
```

but that doesn't work an only opens a blank colorbox with the loading gif.

How do I tell it which group to open? Seems like that's what missing. Adding the `rel:` property to the config settings in the example above only adds that current element to that `rel` group which also stalls it upon opening.
I've also tried using the `href:` property setting it like so `href:'#cb_group1'`, but that only brings up colorbox with the following error: "This content failed to load."

Any ideas?

Comment: a quick fix would be to trigger a click on the `colorbox()`'ed element, with something like `$('#cb_group').click();`

Comment: If you want to use the `href:` property in this fashion, you need to use `inline:true` also

Comment: @DomDay - Yep thanks good point. I just figured that out as I was reading the FAQ - [Create a separate link for opening a gallery](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/faq/#faq-click). I'm fine with that even though it's an extra click thru, unless someone else knows how to directly invoke it.

Comment: @DomDay - I tried `href:` in conjunction with `inline:true`, but then it displays my link in the colorbox instead of the photo group they point to.

Comment: Hmm. looking at [this page](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/) and examining the source to see how he did it shows a call of `$(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});`, and a click link of `<a class="inline cboxElement"href="#inline_content">Inline HTML</a>` . I'm assuming the `cboxElement` class was added by colorbox, in which case it's just an href that's required

Comment: @DomDay - thanks. I did try that, but what that does if you click on the example is bring up the html (an an link and some other text and markup) in a colorbox. In my case, it did exactly the same and brought up the html that renders the link "View Photos (25)" inside the colorbox, not the actual pictures in a colorbox picture gallery.

Comment: @DomDay - I think per the colorbox FAQ I mentioned early [Create a separate link for opening a gallery](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/faq/#faq-click), the author is suggesting to issuing a click event `$gallery.eq(0).click();
` on the anchor you want to bring up from where ever you're at which tells me this is the suggested and only way to accomplish what I'm look for. So your original suggestion was right.